# Hide processes from other users based on groups (under Linux)?

Tags: security, process, selinux, grsecurity, hardening

Is it possible to configure process hiding for certain user groups under a linux system?

For example: Users from group X should not see processes owned by users from group Y in ps/top or under /proc.

Is it possible to configure such a setup with SELinux?

(I vaguely remember a similar feature in the funny grsecurity patch set - but IIRC, it was more generic - and besides, I want to configure a stock linux distro without having to maintain a custom kernel.)

**Edit:** For better illustration, [Solaris 10 has a similar feature](http://blogs.oracle.com/gbrunett/entry/forcing_users_to_see_only). The example is not that generic, but one can configure that a user or some users can only see information of their own processes in ps etc.

Comment: I don't know but the best source of SELinux info is probably the book (amazon link) [SELinux by Example: Using Security Enhanced Linux](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0131963694?ie=UTF8&tag=xenotsblog-20&linkCode=as2&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=0131963694)

Comment: Grsecurity does this for single users except root.

Comment: Similar question with more answers: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17164/how-to-make-a-process-invisible-to-other-users/34224#34224

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, SELinux [seems to allow](http://www.lurking-grue.org/selinuxHOWTO.html) such [configurations](http://www.lurking-grue.org/writingselinuxpolicyHOWTO.html):

From the first [Howto](http://www.lurking-grue.org/selinuxHOWTO.html):

> This time, you will see all processes on the system regardless of the domain they are in. When in sysadm_t domain, you have access to other domains which the user_t domain does not.

From the second [Howto](http://www.lurking-grue.org/writingselinuxpolicyHOWTO.html):

> The third line allows staff_t to run ps and see processes in the unprivileged user domains. staff_t is able to run ps and see everything in user_t and other user domains if any, whereas user_t can not.

Answer (score -1):

Without a rootkit, or without hacking the kernel to specifically allow that behavior, there are not any pre-packaged options.

If these are processes launched from code you have access to then you may be able to recompile it while altering the argv[0] argument passed into the program. This could effectively change the name to something benign and thus "hide" it from anyone checking top or ps, etc.

Comment: actually, there are pre-packaged options ... ;) See my answer for details ...

Comment: @maxschlepzig, thanks for linking to those. I had no idea.