# How can I disable /proc pseudo-filesystem on a shared Linux environment?

Tags: linux, security, process, proc

Is it possible to disable the `/proc` pseudo-filesystem to prevent `w`, `ps`, `top`, etc, from showing what other users are doing?  Of course, I still want "everything else" to work correctly.  Is there a workable way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is the [grsecurity](http://grsecurity.net/) patchset (included in SELinux, but doesn't have the latter's horribly complicated MAC permission system) for the Linux kernel which offers the option of allowing only the owner (and root) to see his/her processes. It also offers other goodies without being as intrusive as SELinux.

A similar option is there on Solaris, or so I heard.

Comment: For Solaris, see [How to Limit Display of Other User's Processes](https://blogs.oracle.com/gbrunett/entry/forcing_users_to_see_only) to configure which users can see what other users are doing.

Answer (score 5):

If you disable `/proc`, a lot of things will stop working. Not only will you not be able to use `ps` and company, even to see your own processes, but a lot of tools and services will not be able to run. Looking at the computer I'm writing this on, processes that have a file under `/proc` open include `mdadm` (RAID), `Xorg` (GUI), `hald` (hotpluggable devices), `acpid` (ACPI), `rpc.mount` (NFS server).

It might be workable to give `/proc` permissions 550 (i.e. non-world-readable), group `proc-readers`, and put all the services that use `/proc` but aren't running as root in the `proc-readers` group. I've never tried; this is an experiment proposal, not something to do on a production machine.

Use [SELinux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1326/hide-processes-from-other-users-based-on-groups-under-linux) or [virtualization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server) to further isolate users.