# I don't want other users see my processes in ps aux. I have root. It's Debian. How to use grsec?

Tags: linux, security, process, grsecurity

I installed 'linux-patch-grsecurity2' and it has some sort of interface.

```
~$ sudo gradm2
gradm 2.1.14
grsecurity administration program

Usage: gradm [option] ...

Examples:
        gradm -P
        gradm -F -L /etc/grsec/learning.logs -O /etc/grsec/policy
Options:
        -E, --enable    Enable the grsecurity RBAC system
        -D, --disable   Disable the grsecurity RBAC system
        -C, --check     Check RBAC policy for errors
        -S, --status    Check status of RBAC system
        -F, --fulllearn Enable full system learning
        -P [rolename], --passwd
                        Create password for RBAC administration
                        or a special role
        -R, --reload    Reload the RBAC system while in admin mode
        -L <filename>, --learn
                        Specify the pathname for learning logs
        -O <filename>, --output
                        Specify where to place policies generated from
                        learning mode
        -M <filename|uid>, --modsegv
                        Remove a ban on a specific file or UID
        -a <rolename> , --auth
                        Authenticates to a special role that requires auth
        -u, --unauth    Remove yourself from your current special role
        -n <rolename> , --noauth
                        Transitions to a special role that doesn't
                        require authentication
        -p <rolename> , --pamauth
                        Authenticates to a special role through PAM
        -V, --verbose   Display verbose policy statistics when enabling system
        -h, --help      Display this help
        -v, --version   Display version information
```

I didn't successfully find any documentation on how to use it to limit the 'ps aux' list for users?

Comment: Related: [how to do it with SELinux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1326/hide-processes-from-other-users-based-on-groups-under-linux).

Comment: Hmm, that subject line kinda sounds like a cracking attempt.

Comment: `kill -9 <your_pid>` :D

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the proper kernel configuration options. Here is the [relevant part](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Grsecurity/Appendix/Grsecurity_and_PaX_Configuration_Options#Restrict_.2Fproc_to_user_only) of the [documentation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Grsecurity). I don't think you can do it from the gradm policy file.

Comment: The reference to the kernel configuration options is vague, and while the answer to the question is indeed in the documentation, you could've been more specific.