# How does ps know to hide passwords?

Tags: security, ps, arguments

Witness:

```
$ ps f
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
31509 pts/3    Ss     0:01 -bash
27266 pts/3    S+     0:00  \_ mysql -uroot -p
25210 pts/10   Ss+    0:00 /bin/bash
24444 pts/4    Ss     0:00 -bash
29111 pts/4    S+     0:00  \_ tmux attach
 4833 pts/5    Ss+    0:00 -bash
 9046 pts/6    Ss     0:00 -bash
17749 pts/6    R+     0:00  \_ ps f
 4748 pts/0    Ss     0:00 -bash
14635 pts/0    T      0:02  \_ mysql -uroot -px xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
16210 pts/0    S+     0:01  \_ mysql -uroot -px xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

How did ps know to hide the `mysql` passwords? Can I incorporate this into my own scripts to hide particular CLI attributes?

Comment: It is probably the other way and `mysql` does the magic, not `ps`: “MySQL clients typically overwrite the command-line password argument with zeros during their initialization sequence.” – [End-User Guidelines for Password Security](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/password-security-user.html)

Comment: Thank you, that is an informative document. I'll see about how I might overwrite cli arguments in my own scripts.

Comment: @manatwork I would put that as an answer, because that is exactly what is happening - and it's a useful link for security issues regarding mysql. :)

Comment: Note that while command line arguments can be snooped, [environment variables are safe](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14000/environment-variable-accessibility-in-linux/14009#14009).

Comment: For a lot more info on this, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/385339/135943

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`ps` does not hide the password. Applications like mysql overwrite arguments list that they got. Please note, that there is a small time frame (possible extendible by high system load), where the arguments are visible to other applications until they are overwritten. [Hiding the process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/34224/15241) to other users could help. In general it is much better to pass passwords via files than per command line.

In [this article](http://netsplit.com/2007/01/10/hiding-arguments-from-ps/) it is described for C, how to do this. 
The following example hides/deletes all command line arguments:

```
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // process command line arguments....

    // hide command line arguments
    if (argc > 1) {
        char *arg_end;    
        arg_end = argv[argc-1] + strlen (argv[argc-1]);
        *arg_end = ' ';
    }

    // ...
}
```

Look also at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724582/hide-arguments-from-ps and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830823/hiding-secret-from-command-line-parameter-on-unix .

Comment: Very nice, thanks. I did not realize that the arguments are mutable as such.

Comment: Also note that not all programs will do this with passwords.

Comment: The link to [this article](http://netsplit.com/2007/01/10/hiding-arguments-from-ps/) is broken. Anyone to explain the code for me?(Why the code work, just set `\0` to space?) Any link to `setproctitle()`?

Comment: Or the answer lies [here](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.31/fs/proc/base.c#L270)?

Answer (score 7):

The **mysql** program replaces the password from the command line with `x` in [this line of code](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysql/mysql-server/5.5/view/head:/client/mysql.cc#L1734):

```
while (*argument) *argument++= 'x';     // Destroy argument
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not as secure as it could be. You can tell how long the password is. It's better to replace it with `\0` so that you need extra information to find the password length (without UB / SEGFAULT).