# Can I mask a program on the OS from the command line?

Tags: shell

So, I wanted to know if it was possible to mask a running program (not visible from task manager) from the command line. Also, can I see all programs, hidden or otherwise from the command line?

Comment: there is a discussion about this topic here:http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17164/how-to-make-a-process-invisible-to-other-users

Comment: Install a rootkit?